# How to match columns both forward and reverse direction in a data_frame using r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframe.

df1:

```
      P_1  P_2
1     Anb  Bmn
2     Cvd  Dbn
3     Elf  Fish
4     Goat Hen
5     Ink  Jelly
6     Kin  Lion
7     ACAN HSPG
8     HSPG2 COL6A2
```

df2:

```
    P_1  P_2 Value
   1   Anb  Bmn    12
   2   Dbn  Cvd    31
   3   Elf Fish    15
   4  Goat  Hen    98
   5 Jelly  Ink    78
   6   Kin Lion    56
   7  HSPG ACAN    89
```

I tried to merge these two dataframe based on P_1 and P_2 using following command

```
e<-merge(df1,df2, by=c("P_1","P_2"),all.x=TRUE)
```

But for the row 2 , 5 and 7, I got 'NA'. This is because, the order is changed. But in the output I need the value even the order is changed. How do I achieve this?

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(P_1 = c("Anb", "Cvd", "Elf", "Goat", "Ink", "Kin","ACAN"," HSPG2"), P_2 = c("Bmn", "Dbn", "Fish", "Hen", "Jelly", "Lion","HSPG","COL6A2")), class = "data.frame",row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
df2 <- structure(list(P_1 = c("Anb", "Dbn", "Elf", "Goat", "Jelly", "Kin","HSPG"), P_2 = c("Bmn","Cvd", "Fish", "Hen", "Ink", "Lion","ACAN"), Value = c(12L, 31L, 15L, 98L, 78L,56L,89L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3","4","5", "6","7"))
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Are you updating with the original data or the new one

Comment: Now, the Data part looks like the original one you posted

Comment: I am sorry. Now it is done

Comment: can you check my update.  Your expected seems to be not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the order to be same, we need to `sort` by row for each of the datasets

```
df1new <- df1
df1new[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, sort))
df2new <- df2
df2new[1:2] <- t(apply(df2new[1:2], 1, sort))
```

and now do the `merge`

```
merge(df1new, df2new, all.x = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(P_1 = c("A", "C", "E", "G", "I", "K", "z", "w"), P_2 = c("B", "D", "F", "H", "J", "L", "b", "c")), class = "data.frame",row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
df2 <- structure(list(P_1 = c("A", "D", "E", "H", "J", "K"), P_2 = c("B", "C", "F", "G", "I", "L"), Value = c(12L, 31L, 15L, 98L, 78L, 56L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4","5", "6"))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer. But It doesn't always have follow some of order (like alphabetic). In that case, How do I achieve?

Comment: @SteffiMa can you please update with an example in your post

Comment: @SteffiMa can you please check the `dput`, it is not complete